# Scheduling a periodic JobService only if it is not scheduled already

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jobscheduler

I'm trying to schedule a periodic job service like below.

The problem here is that `jobScheduler.getPendingJob(jobId)` always returns null after the job is executed once, i.e., `jobScheduler.allPendingJobs` does not have my job after it is executed the first time.

I do not want to schedule it again because I end up running the job twice within the same period.

If I don't reschedule it, then the job runs perfectly fine, every hour.

```
fun scheduleAnalyticsJob() {
    logPendingJobs()

    val jobId = analyticsJobsId
    LogUtil.debug(this, "Analytics job id [$jobId].")

    val job = JobInfo.Builder(
        jobId,
        ComponentName(appContext, ScheduledAnalyticsJob::class.java)
    )
        .setRequiresCharging(false)
        .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
        .setPeriodic(IntervalMillis.hour)
        .setPersisted(true)
        .build()

    val pendingJob = jobScheduler.getPendingJob(jobId)
    if (pendingJob == null) {
        LogUtil.debug(this, "Rescheduling analytics job.")
        jobScheduler.schedule(job)
    } else if (pendingJob != job) {
        LogUtil.debug(this, "Rescheduling analytics job since params changed.")
        jobScheduler.cancel(jobId)
        jobScheduler.schedule(job)
    } else {
        LogUtil.debug(this, "Analytics Job already scheduled.")
    }
}
```